# Importing .anim files created using the Unity Animation controls

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, importing, mecanim

Our artist created some .anim files using the built-in Unity Mecanim system (where you use keyframes and drag various body parts to construct the animation).

However, now we're trying to export them from her Unity program into mine so that I can incorporate them into the scene. The problem is that they're simply appearing as blank files.

Here, the files are importing and everything looks fine aside from the controller:

[image: Here, the files are importing and everything looks fine aside from the controller.]

However, once it's imported, it just shows up as a blank/unrecognized file:

[image: However, once it's imported, it just shows up as a blank/unrecognized file.]

She's exporting everything as a .unitypackage and I'm importing the .unitypackage, but it doesn't work for some reason.

In addition, she was able to create a new project on her computer and import the package fine. Any ideas why mine is funking up?

Comment: Use git my friend. Importing exporting asets is a preistorical method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply an error with her and my Unity versions being different. By updating my version of Unity, that solved the issue. Apparently files need to come from the same Unity version to be compatible!